# 旮旯 in 緣路山旮旯 (a film in Hong Kong)

Tags: word

There is a film produced in Hongkong in 2021.  The name is 緣路山旮旯.  I would like to ask about the construction of some sentences with 旮旯 except 山旮旯.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It's believed that 旮旯 is cognate with 角落.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[山旮旯](https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E5%B1%B1%E6%97%AE%E6%97%AF) is a Cantonese common phrase,

> 指偏僻的山區 (a remote mountainous area)

[旮旯](https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E6%97%AE%E6%97%AF) means 'corner'. It is not used independently by modern Cantonese.

Similar to 黷 (wantonly engage) in [窮兵黷武](https://cantoneseplus.com/word/175239) is no longer used independently by modern Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

No other comments.  Just want to post an alternative answer:

> 不受注意的偏僻角落

[image]

one of the origin:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

東京灣
波斯灣
戈壁灘
要看就要夠狠
多山旮旯 有我同行
過眼浮雲 還應捉緊

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IywmMeF69w&list=RD5IywmMeF69w&start_radio=1